# update running balance using hibernate in multiuser environment

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, api, save

**The following is a table structure**

[image]

**Formula**

Balance = Original Amount + Balance(Previous)

50=50+0    **ID(1)**

200=150+50 **ID(2)**

with respect to the second row, how we can update balance using hibernate **session.save();** I have tried to write out insert query but come to know that HQL Does not support insert with value but with select from other table.

`In HQL, only the INSERT INTO … SELECT … is supported; there is no INSERT INTO … VALUES. HQL only support insert from another table.` **[[source]](http://fukyo-it.blogspot.com/2012/01/hibernate-query-examples-hql.html)**

If using hibernate, `I first get the balance of max id of customer 1` and `then pass the balance to the new object` , then it will be ok!

but in multi-user  environment, as `one user get the balance of max id of customer 1`, meanwhile `other user insert the new row and update the balance`. then first user who get the balance is old `because when first user transaction geting the balance other user insert new row and update balance`. In this case first user transaction insert the wrong balance with respect to the previous balance that he get before updating second user transaction.

is hibernate have bulletin feature to control this type of situation ?

How we can save the transaction using hibernate session.save() with up-to-date balance. ?

Update me !

Comment: How should hibernate know about the dependency of row 2 to row 1?

Answer (score 0):

Since the entities representing the table rows are independent of each other, hibernate can not know that the calculation of the balance is based on outdated data.

**Solution 1 (by far my preferred one): Calculate the balance in the db (using triggers)** and mark the balance attribute as

> @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)

so that the entity will be updated after a write. Hibernate and database will take care of the rest.

If you have to do the balance calculation on the application level multiple solutions with some drawbacks come to mind:

**Solution 2: Don't use user transactions to commit multi-user dependent data.**

Create something (e.g. some queuing mechanism) to serialize the save requests. Do the processing in a user independent transaction.

Drawback: The user won't see the balance as it is stored in the db (but you might display a transient "forecasted balance" doing your current calculation) and you have a more complicated application logic and a bottle neck through serialization.

**Solution 3: Write (potentially) wrong data (or leave it empty) - update afterwards**

If you would store the ID of the entity you use for calculation with the new entity, you could check for duplicates (two entities with balances based on the same entity) and update the value.

Drawback: Similar to Solution 2, but without the bottleneck since the update could be done in a background task.

**Solution 4: Refactor the data model to remove the dependency between the entities (for writes).**

You could make the balance transient (and calculate it if you have to display or use it).

Drawback: Only works for moderate numbers of entries and removes this datum from the db which might hinder some queries you might want to perform